# Problem with Tika parseToString call

Tags: apache-poi, apache-tika

I'm using POI for extracting data from excel file. (the 5th column in the excel sheet contain names of files that exist in my filesystem)
I loop over the table's rows (extract the cell's content with POI) and for each row I create instance of Tika, and I parse the files that named in the 5th column with Tika "parseToString(file)", when the file is Office document (excel, ppt, word) I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: filesystem
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:185)
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:131)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.parse(WordExtractor.java:61)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:182)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
    at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:357)
    at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:423)
    at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:403)
    at HP.BuildMailExcelDoc.getTextFromTika(BuildMailExcelDoc.java:355)
    at HP.BuildMailExcelDoc.addExcelDoc(BuildMailExcelDoc.java:314)
    at HP.BuildMailExcelDoc.buildDoc(BuildMailExcelDoc.java:196)
    at HP.BuildMailExcelDoc.buildMailDoc(BuildMailExcelDoc.java:102)
    at HP.BuildMailExcelDoc.indexDirectory(BuildMailExcelDoc.java:69)
    at HP.BuildMailExcelDoc.indexDirectory(BuildMailExcelDoc.java:78)
    at HP.BuildMailExcelDoc.buildDoc(BuildMailExcelDoc.java:63)
    at HP.IndexGUI$1.mouseClicked(IndexGUI.java:281)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think this problem occur as result from the nested use in POI.
once in the excel table and then once again in the Tika parsing call.

Is it sound reasonable? how can i handle this problem?

Thanks :-)
Reuth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have two copies of POI on your classpath. I'd guess you have the new version that Tika supplied, along with an older one. The issue is that Java is picking up the first version on your classpath, which is the old one.

Your solution is to remove the old version from your classpath. See [this POI FAQ Entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) for how to identify where the old copy comes from